# Is it possible to add to an empty arrayList at random indexes?

Tags: java

For example i want to add the 1 object to the first index, then i want to add a another object to index 5. So i haven't added anything to 2,3,4,5. Is this possible?

The main reason i want to do this is because i have 2 kinds of activities. I want to store the first kind of activity on the list from 1-5 and the second from 6-10. So this way when i ask the user for what kind of activity she is looking for (first type or second type) i will know which part of the array list to start looking at.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use two array lists?

Comment: From Arraylist Javadoc: "IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range (index < 0 || index > size())". You could use an array, though.

Comment: Yes, but only if you use some kind of [`SparseArrayList`](http://software.clapper.org/javautil/api/org/clapper/util/misc/SparseArrayList.html).

Comment: I do hope you are not thinking of storing 10 Android `Activity` instances in _anything_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not possible. You'll get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if you try to add something to an index that exceeds the current list size.

But you can initialize your list with an "empty" instance of your list type (or `null` if you take care) first and use `set` instead of `add`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> l = initList();
    l.set(0, "activity 1");
    l.set(5, "activity 2");
    System.out.println(l);
}

private static List<String> initList() {
    final List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        l.add(""); // or null, but this can cause some problems ... (try to find an empty representation for an "activity" instance)
    }
    return l;
}
```

Output:

```
[activity 1, null, null, null, null, activity 2, null, null, null, null]
```

It is necessary to use `set` instead of `add`, or you're increasing the size of the list with every `add` call. This will shift current entries on higher indices (element on index `6` will then be on index `7` if you add someting on an index below `6`).
So you should think about your current concept. Maybe it is easier to use two lists or an array instead.

Comment: In the add part i intend to have a constructor of the other object class which will create the object. Can i just use l.add(null)? What is the problem with that? Also could you please tell me how would i be able to write a condition statment to check wether that index is null, if so do something.

Comment: @user4188409 Yes, you can use `l.add(null)`. The problem is, that you have to check if the element returned by `list.get(5)` is `null` (a placeholder) or a real activity that you've stored there. This is necessary to avoid a `NullPointerException`. For the check, just write `if (list.get(index) == null) { list.set(index, new MyActivity()); }`.

Comment: Thank you very much, i just have a final question. Do i have to use if (list.get(index) == null) or can i not just use if (list(index) == null)?

Comment: you can use `if (list(index) == null)` if `list` is a method that returns an `Object` type. You cannot access a specific element of the List `list` with it. You have to use `list.get(index)` for this. ([JavaDoc for List.get](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get%28int%29))

Comment: Yes, my arraylist has objects in  them, so if (list(index) == null) should be good then.

Comment: @user4188409 as I said, it is only possible if `list()` is a method and not the `List` itself.

Answer (score 1):

Not normally, no, because this is not how the List abstraction works. A List has a variable size and its size is equal to the number of elements it contains. It provides access by numerical index, but only to the indices of its existing elements.

You can do this *yourself* by padding with `null`, for example:

```
public static void ensureSize(List<?> inList, int numIndices) {
    if(inList.size() >= numIndices) {
        return;
    }

    for(; numIndices > 0; --numIndices) {
        inList.add(null);
    }
}
```

Be aware that with this approach that:

- Your List now contains `null` elements until they are `set` to something else (as would an array).
- Calling `add` and `remove` on a List causes the indexing of the elements to change. Make sure you are appropriately using `set` and `get`.

However, if the size of your List is known ahead of time and fixed, it may very well be appropriate to simply use an array.

If you just want to go through the List interface because you find it easy to work with, you might also initialize it with [`Arrays#asList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-):

```
//           ( java.util.Arrays )
List<String> fixedList = Arrays.asList(new String[n]);
```

This creates a List with a fixed size that wraps around the array. You can `set` and `get` on it but not `add` and `remove`. (Calling `add`, `remove` and other methods that attempt to alter the size will throw an exception.)

Comment: Careful with this approach, because people tend to do `List<Whatever> list = ...; for(Whatever w : list) { ... }` and you may encounter with `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza You're right, but that is also the normal behavior of an array. So the danger is that it breaks expectations of the List abstraction.

Comment: Then just use a plain array instead, there's no need to use a `List`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I agree with that. That's why I also recommended `asList` since the OP might just be familiar with List. List has additional functionality like `contains`, `indexOf`, etc, adjunct from its resizing behavior.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do this then see Apache Commons Collections Growth list

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/list/GrowthList.html

Answer (score 0):

For an `ArrayList`, this is possible only if the random index is between 0 and `yourArrayList.size()`. Otherwise, you will get `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. This is clearly stated at javadoc of [`ArrayList#add(int, E)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-int-E-).

For your case, it would be better to use plain array rather than an ArrayList.

Comment: I know my arraylist will have 10 elements in it. And i know i will never add an item to an index which already has an item. So if i add to an index, say 5, and there is no item in that index will all the indexes to the right be pushed 1 head? Or will they all remain the same?

Comment: @user4188409 If you use `add` with a specific index, then every element with a greater index will be shifted one "place" to the right, even if they are `null` elements. Use `List.set(index, element)` to replace a placeholder element.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform this only by first initializing the list with dummy value and then later you can replace its different indexes according to you wish.

For eg: 
ArrayList strList = new ArrayList();

If your lists size is always constant, say 6, then first initialize it with some dummy values as 
[ , , , , , ]
Now you can use the range from the size for "first type" and "second type". Lets take 3 each. You can set each range by using set:

strList.set(0, "first type 1");

strList.set(4, "second type 2");

To be frank, instead of going for this approach, the best would be to use two separate lists for different activities.